# Javassist Enhancement failed for all configured Hibernate mappings

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I' m trying to migrate from developing a java web app using Eclipse to VS Code.

I used to run/debug locally on Tomcat9.0.6 with Hibernate 4.3.4 using the [Eclipses Tomcat plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-tomcat-plugin).This works fine.
When I try to run the app through the [Tomcat plugin for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adashen.vscode-tomcat) however, I get these kind of stacktraces for every entity configured using a {class}.hbm.xml.:

```
[apache-tomcat-9.0.6.vs]: 2021-02-16 11:35:22,ERROR,,org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer,main,4053,JavassistLazyInitializer.java,165,JavassistLazyInitializer,getProxyFactory HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: {fully.qualified.ClassName}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor52.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor51.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at com.onesparrow.commons.orm.hibernate.DbHibernate.init(DbHibernate.java:61)
    at com.onesparrow.commons.orm.DbRepository.addDb(DbRepository.java:59)
    at eu.sonetas.fuga.controller.InitController.initCustomerDbs(InitController.java:463)
    at eu.sonetas.fuga.controller.InitController.init(InitController.java:312)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5075)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1142)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1054)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
```

I run the app in VS Code by making a war for my web app and then using the VS Code plugin's "Run War on Tomcat Server" context menu option.

I suspect the Eclipse plugin passes some parameters which the VS Code plugin doesn't, but I'm completely at a loss here. Any suggestions would be appreciated at this point.

Comment: https://twitter.com/howlger/status/1358189525424459777

Comment: Yeah, except Eclipse has no integrated terminal or support for working on remotes. Funny joke, not really helpful though...

And if they were actually the same it would just work

Comment: It is actually the same except for the Tomcat plugin/extension. Knowing this, it should be clear that the documentation of the VS Code Tomcat extension should tell you where or how to set `fully.qualified.ClassName`. If you can't figure it out yourself, link to the Tomcat extension you are using ([this one?](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adashen.vscode-tomcat)). And by the way, the _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers_ is shipped with [_TM Terminal_](https://www.eclipse.org/tm/) which provides a _Terminal_ view and more for working on remotes.

Comment: I'm using the one you linked, it doesn't have very useful docs so if you could help me out telling VS Code Tomcat extension where/how to set those class names

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer your question. I read the question because it was tagged with _eclipse_, but knowledge about Eclipse is not needed here. Seems to be a Hibernate thing. Did you try setting `fully.qualified.ClassName` manually: `-Dfully.qualified.ClassName=...`?

Comment: I actuall think this is a result of the VS code extension not being able to launch Tomcat using another JVM than 11 (https://github.com/adashen/vscode-tomcat/issues/317)

Comment: If so and according to [this comment](https://github.com/adashen/vscode-tomcat/issues/317#issuecomment-770352619), the Java in `settings.json` (VS Code Tomcat extension) must match the Java version in `.classpath` (Java Extensions by RedHat = Eclipse).

Comment: Yup that did the trick

Comment: Great. You might add a self-answer, comment on the GitHub issue, and change your mind that the joke wasn't helpful though. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging I found out the reason this happened was Tomcat starting with JRE 11 instead of 9.

To change this I found [this](https://github.com/adashen/vscode-tomcat/issues/317) issue.